# Turning eslint rule off in eslintrc.json

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to disable `jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid` in `eslintrc.json`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md#rule-details), the relevant rule block looks like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
            "components": [ "Link" ],
            "specialLink": [ "hrefLeft", "hrefRight" ],
            "aspects": [ "noHref", "invalidHref", "preferButton" ]
          }]
    }
}
```

This used to work before I upgraded `create-react-app` to version 2.0, where my eslint rule was simply `"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0`.

I have read the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules) which says that we can simply change `error` into `off`, although I have tried that to no avail.

What is the correct way to disable the rule and what is the documentation that I should be referencing?

Comment: `"off"` should be correct as far as I know.  Are you leaving the `Object` after the `"off"` or are you just leaving the literal: `"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "off"]`?

Comment: hi @zero298, thank you for the reply. I've tried `["off"]`, `"off"`, `["off", {}]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like this is a new addition to create react app. The point is to convert the `href` into a `button` if possible.

Adding `"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0` to `.eslintrc.json` is correct. This prevents errors from showing up when running `eslint`, but does not prevent errors from showing up in the CRA console.

Alternatives such as `// eslint-disable-next-line` or `href="#/"` can be used although perhaps unrecommended. Check out the discussion [here](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/485) for more information.